# Why does my Windows 7 computer wake itself up from sleep mode?

Tags: windows-7

I have XPS9100 DELL desktop computer awakes out of the sleep mode without me prompting it.

I have 64 bit OS

Before I go to sleep I put that in sleep mode but in the morning I see its awake and I try every setting possible but could not help

I have tried this command and here is what I got and I am not sure what to do.

```
C:\Users\NAME>powercfg -lastwake
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 1
  Wake Source [0]
    Type: Wake Timer
    Owner: [SERVICE] \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\svchost.exe (wuauserv)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computer is set to automatically install updates at a specific time of day (or more likely, night). The message you posted indicates that Windows Update woke the computer to install updates.

If your computers are centrally managed, you can change the time of day that this happens (or disable it) in Group Policy; if it's standalone you can change it in Windows Update's settings.

Comment: 1+ wow i see that in windows update setting, it set to install 3:00 am no wonder why it wakes up - thank you